# Test windows phone 8.1 app update, after app is published once in store

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store

I have build a windows phone 8.1 app, and i have published it in Windows Store.
Now i want to do an update, but before i want to test it in several devices. I created a package flight but it is only for windows os 10. How can i test in devices that have windows 8.1 os version?

Comment: Can not realy understand your question. You have 8.1 app. So it means that you should also have package for 8.1.

Comment: i have the package but how can i put in store and make visible only for specific people?

Answer (score 1):

When you publish application in Windows Store you can have a package for Windows 8.1 and for Windows 10. Even more - you can have multiple packages depend of build version.

When you fill the submission in Pricing and availability you can find option:

[image]

This way you can make it available for specific people

Comment: For clarification, you can choose third or fourth option; either "only allow this app to be downloaded by specific people", or "only allow people with a download code to download it", and either of those will get you what you want.

Comment: Thank you, @AlexVanLiew. Right, I have mean this

Comment: This happens in case that the package is going to be published in windows store. For the moment i don't want to make it visible, because i have one version of app in store.